# \includegraphics, try another extension

Tags: graphics, external-files

I have a number of documents ([jupyter notebooks](http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what_is_jupyter.html)) that are created
and accessed essentially using a browser interface, and because of the
browser interface the cleanest way to include external vector pictures
in a document is using the [SVG](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/About.html) format.

Those documents [can be converted](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to LaTeX documents, and while it's
easy to add further material to the produced file, in terms of loading
packages, redefining commands etc it is not so easy to modify the rest
of the produced text, that in particular comprises lines like

```
\includegraphics{my_picture.svg}
```

that `pdflatex` does not appreciate at all.

My question, is it possible to redefine `\includegraphics` so that
`pdflatex` tries to load `my_picture.pdf` when it is instructed to
load `my_picture.svg`?

I know that I can have an automatic conversion from `.svg` to `pdf` but
due to other reasons I *already* have the `.pdf` files (that are, in
effect, produced using LateX and later converted to `.svg`)

---

P.S. It is possible to post-process the LaTeX file, as produced by the conversion procedure, before running `pdflatex` (or should I say pre-process?) but I'd like to avoid this intermediate step.

Comment: Just use `\includegraphics{my_picture}`  without extension.

Comment: @Bernard, by _"it is not so easy to modify the rest of the produced text"_ I tried to express that I cannot easily remove the extension — otoh it's very easy to add stuff in the prologue, so I try to follow this course of action.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: Would regular expressions search and replace be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Copy to a new name, use "replace all" and pray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a graphics rule (I didn't test if it works for all sort of pathes and curious file names):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto\Gin@extensions{svg,}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.svg}{pdf}{.pdf}{\noexpand\Gin@base.pdf}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example-image-A.svg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrike, not only your solution works but works at the right level, defining a new file extension and declaring the intended behaviour right inside of the `graphics` machinery... Accepted & upvoted.

Comment: Does this only work with pdflatex?  With xelatex it raises an error: `Unable to load picture or PDF file 'example-image-A.svg'.`

Comment: @Clément no it doesn't work with xelatex.

Answer (score 3):

It is always possible to redefine a command, the question is : will it break something if I do it? If you are certain that `\includegraphics` is used *only* to import svg files, than this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\oig\includegraphics
\def\topdf#1.svg{#1.pdf}
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\oig[#1]{\topdf#2}}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{test.svg}
\end{document}
```

Macro `\topdf` strips off the `svg`extension and replaces it with `pdf`:
`\topdf lalala.svg -> lalala.pdf` (no braces around the argument).

Comment: Thank you Christoph, your solution works but it is rather _ad hoc_ and limiting w/r to other uses of `graphics`. I've upvoted it (it works) but there is a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, I learned something too with Ulrike's answer :)