# xelatex and \DeclareGraphicsRule

Tags: graphics, xetex, external-files

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316445/74057), motivated from my use of [`nbconvert`](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert), I asked about including a pdf file when the `\includegraphics` command explicitly referenced a svg file. Now `nbconvert` uses no more `pdflatex` but uses `xelatex` instead, and this is relevant...

[Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316469/74057) to the question referenced above,

```
...
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto\Gin@extensions{svg,}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.svg}{pdf}{.pdf}{\noexpand\Gin@base.pdf}
\makeatother
...
```

works like a charm with both `pdflatex` and `lualatex` but fails with `xelatex`, e.g.

```
$ cat text1.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
  \preto\Gin@extensions{svg,}
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{.svg}{pdf}{.pdf}{\noexpand\Gin@base.pdf}
\makeatother
\begin{document} \includegraphics{trab1_conv.svg} \end{document}
$ xelatex text1
...
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in trab1_conv.pdf (no BoundingBox).
...
No pages of output.
Transcript written on text1.log.
$
```

To make me more confused, `trab1_conv.pdf` is a perfectly sane pdf,

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e s/conv.svg/conv.pdf/ text1.tex
$ xelatex text1
...
<use  "trab1_conv.pdf" > [1] (./text1.aux) )
Output written on text1.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on text1.log.
$
```

It is easy to circumvent the problem (just generate the `.tex` file and run `pdflatex` on it) but I'd like to understand what is happening between XeLaTeX an `\declareGraphicsRule`.

Tia — g

ps: the recipe to produce the external files is

```
latex trab1_conv.tex ; pdf2svg trab1_conv.pdf trab1_conv.svg
```

where `trab1_conv.tex` produces a standalone image of your liking.

Comment: XeTeX doesn't produce PDF directly, unlike pdfTeX and LuaTeX. So you would need to take account of the backend you are using, I think, since all graphics-inclusion stuff is backend-dependent, as I understand it. And XeTeX can use at least two different backends, I think, so it might depend on which you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XeTeX pass graphics type like pdf (or png) to the QuickTime library to get their bounding box. The problem is that it quite stubbornly insist to pass the original file and seems not to contain code to declare an alias extension to use instead to get the file size. You can try the following. I didn't test it extensively but imho it shouldn't disturb other graphic formats:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{ifxetex}

\makeatletter
\preto\Gin@extensions{svg,}

\ifxetex
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{.svg}{QTm}{QTm}{\noexpand\Gin@base.pdf}
  \pretocmd\Gread@QTm{\ifdefstring\Gin@ext{.svg}{\def\Gin@ext{.pdf}}{}}{}{\fail}
\else
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{.svg}{pdf}{.pdf}{\noexpand\Gin@base.pdf}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example-image-A.svg}

\end{document}
```