# Inclusion of graphics with on-the-fly conversion using XeTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, includegraphics, shell-escape, moodle

I would like to make `\inclugraphics{file.ext}` perform on-the-fly conversion of graphics files  with unsupported formats, e.g. `.ext` is `.svg` or `.gif`.

This use case happens at least with the package `moodle.sty`, where users might want to include local graphic files adapted to the web (SVG, GIF), and have them passed as-is to the XML output.
This XML output contains a question bank to be imported in the Moodle LMS for building quizzes.
In order to keep the process as simple as possible for the user, I would like to avoid requiring that two versions of the graphic file are manually kept synchronized locally (one for the XML, one for the standard LaTeX output file).

Here is a MWE that compiles without error and does what I expect with: Linux, ImageMagick for conversion, TeX Live 2020 and both compilation calls `pdflatex -shell-escape MWE.tex` and `lualatex -shell-escape MWE.tex`.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\edef\Gin@extensions{\Gin@extensions,.svg}%
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.svg}{png}{.png}{%
    `convert '#1' \noexpand\Gin@base-svg-converted-to.png
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{pict.svg}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="10" height="10" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 10 10" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4"/>
</svg>
```

```latex
\end{filecontents*}
This is a black disk: \includegraphics{pict}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I am failing to make this work with XeTeX.
Here are parts of the log file when using `\tracingmacros1`

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.10.2)  11 DEC 2020 11:20
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**MWE.tex
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17>
...
\Gin@ext ->.svg

\Gin@rule@.svg #1->{png}{.png}{`convert '#1' \Gin@base -svg-converted-to.png }
#1<-\Gin@base \Gin@ext 

\Gin@setfile #1#2#3->\ifx \\#2\\\Gread@false \fi \ifGin@bbox \else \ifGread@ \c
sname Gread@\expandafter \ifx \csname Gread@#1\endcsname \relax eps\else #1\fi 
\endcsname {\Gin@base #2}\else \Gin@nosize {#3}\fi \fi \Gin@viewport@code \Gin@
nat@height \Gin@ury bp\advance \Gin@nat@height -\Gin@lly bp\Gin@nat@width \Gin@
urx bp\advance \Gin@nat@width -\Gin@llx bp\Gin@req@sizes \expandafter \ifx \csn
ame Ginclude@#1\endcsname \relax \Gin@drafttrue \expandafter \ifx \csname Gread
@#1\endcsname \relax \@latex@error {Can not include graphics of type: #1}\@ehc 
\global \expandafter \let \csname Gread@#1\endcsname \@empty \fi \fi \leavevmod
e \ifGin@draft \hb@xt@ \Gin@req@width {\vrule \hss \vbox to \Gin@req@height {\h
rule \@width \Gin@req@width \vss \edef \@tempa {#3}\rlap { \ttfamily \expandaft
er \strip@prefix \meaning \@tempa }\vss \hrule }\hss \vrule }\else \@addtofilel
ist {#3}\ProvidesFile {#3}[Graphic file (type #1)]\setbox \z@ \hbox {\csname Gi
nclude@#1\endcsname {#3}}\dp \z@ \z@ \ht \z@ \Gin@req@height \wd \z@ \Gin@req@w
idth \box \z@ \fi 
#1<-png
#2<-.png
#3<-`convert '\Gin@base \Gin@ext ' \Gin@base -svg-converted-to.png 

\Gread@eps #1->\Gread@generic {#1}\Gread@eps@aux 
#1<-\Gin@base .png
...
->\errmessage  LaTeX Error: File `\Gin@base .png' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help\@err@                                     
                              

\Gin@base ->pict

\@err@                                                                  ->
! LaTeX Error: File `pict.png' not found.
```

Since the file `pict.png` is not created, I guess that the call to `convert` is not made.

Here is what I tried unsuccessfully:

- removing the part `-svg-converted-to` in the `\DeclareGraphicsRule` does not help (still the conversion call is not made I guess)
- `epstopdf` [does not seem to help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47648/228515)
- solutions involving the QuickTime library seem to be macOS-only, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368848/228515) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44090/228515)

My questions are:

- Am I missing something obvious?
- Why is the conversion call not made when compiling with XeTeX?
- Is there something we can do specifically for XeTeX to achieve what the MWE does with pdfTeX and LuaTeX?

Comment: I would avoid to setup the system so that `--shell-escape` is required. That is a security risk. Beside this: on windows the name of the command is not `convert` (at least not always).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the `moodle` package actually requires `-shell-escape` already for conversion to base64.

Comment: Here I am trying to figure out if the thing is feasible with XeTeX. We could adapt later for `gswin64c.exe` or any other conversion tool.

Comment: well I don't think that the backtick syntax is supported there (with dvips it doesn't work either), and `-svg-converted-to` is certainly specific to pdflatex/lualatex. You would probably have to hook into the image reading commands. Something like this (that is for dvips, so needs adaption): https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=52778507#52778507

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot! With your pointer I got it working. With additional package `shellesc`, `\DeclareGraphicsRule{.svg}{svg}{.svg}{}\def\Gread@svg#1{ \IfFileExists{#1}\ShellEscape{convert '#1' '#1'.png}}{} \edef\Gin@base{\Gin@base.svg}\edef\Gin@ext{.png}\let\Ginclude@svg=\Ginclude@bmp\Gread@bmp{#1.xbb}}`. Probably not the most elegant solution, though.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you have references for the backtick syntax with XeTeX? Isn't that weird that my `xetex.def` contrains lines like ``@namedef{Gin@rule@.eps.gz}#1{{eps}{.eps.xbb}{`gunzip -c #1}}`` ?

Comment: @mgk I believe that the backtick lines have been copied from dvips.def (which used to support calling arbitrary shell commands via this syntax in more trusting times) as far as I can see looking at the dvipdfmx sources and manual this has never worked in xetex. Sorry we should fix that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the feedback. I posted a tentative answer to this question. I hope the story is correctly told.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to answer my own question after receiving help from Ulrike Fisher and David Carlisle.

**Disclaimer**: running TeX engines with the `-shell-escape` option is to be considered risky for general use. When doing this, you should either trust the files and executables on your system or use a sandboxed environment for compilation.

> Am I missing something obvious?

Well... Maybe I will learn not to expect too much from things that are not documented. The [grfguide](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/grfguide) says that the last argument of `\DeclareGraphicsRule` is usually empty and shows an example where this argument is a system command (`zcat...`) preceded with a backtick (`). It is not said that it will work with any command nor any TeX engine.

> Why is the conversion call not made when compiling with XeTeX?

As David Carlisle and Joseph Wright [pointed out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56410233#56410233), the backtick syntax never worked with XeTeX. This engine performs no graphics conversion by default and outputs a file in the XDV format. A PDF file is obtained after a processing by `dvipdfmx`. In this separate pass, if necessary, graphics are converted. The `graphics` bundle defines no interface to pass conversion commands from TeX to `dvipdfmx`.

> Is there something we can do specifically for XeTeX to achieve what the MWE does with pdfTeX and LuaTeX?

Playing with `graphics` internals, I came up with a solution that seems to work with latex, pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex. The interface of the command `\DeclareGraphicsAlien` is inspired by `\DeclareGraphicsRule` and [epstopdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg)'s`\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule`.
The three arguments are:

1. the alien extension (including leading dot) that is declared,
2. the target native extension (including leading dot) to map it to,
3. system command for conversion using `\SourceFile` and `\OutputFile` for referring to the source file (alien format) and the result of the conversion process (native format).

```latex
\usepackage{graphicx}% including pictures
\usepackage{shellesc}% run system commands from TeX engine
\usepackage{etoolbox}% for \csdef, \csletcs
\makeatletter
\def\@firstofthree#1#2#3{#1}%
\def\@secondofthree#1#2#3{#2}%
\newcommand{\DeclareGraphicsAlien}[3]{%
  \edef\Gin@extensions{#1,\Gin@extensions}%
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{#1}{\@gobble#1}{#1}{}%
  \csdef{Gread@\@gobble#1}##1{%
    \edef\SourceFile{\Gin@base\Gin@ext}%
    \edef\Gin@base{\Gin@base-\@gobble#1-converted-to}%
    \edef\Gin@ext{#2}%
    \edef\OutputFile{\Gin@base\Gin@ext}%
    \edef\targetfmt{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                    \@firstofthree\csname Gin@rule@\Gin@ext\endcsname\relax}%
    \edef\targetext{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                    \@secondofthree\csname Gin@rule@\Gin@ext\endcsname\relax}%
    \IfFileExists{\SourceFile}{\ShellEscape{#3}}{}%
    \csletcs{Ginclude@\@gobble#1}{Ginclude@\targetfmt}%
    \csname Gread@\targetfmt\endcsname{\Gin@base\targetext}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
```

*(this is guaranteed 100% Cargo Cult Programming, bugs and room for improvement are to be expected)*

Now, we can 1) declare an alien format, 2) pair it with a native format of the TeX engine used, and 3) specify the command line to be used for conversion.

Here is an example using two FOSS Swiss Army Knives: ImageMagick and Inkscape, for raster and vector images, respectively. I used the SVG file from the question (named `vector.svg` here) and this [animated GIF](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Balle.gif) (`raster.svg`).

```
\usepackage{iftex}% determine TeX engine
\ifnum 0\ifPDFTeX 1\fi\ifpdf 0\fi=1% EPS is a native format with latex
  \DeclareGraphicsAlien{.svg}{.eps}{%
    inkscape --export-type=eps --export-area-page '\SourceFile' -o 
    '\OutputFile' 2>/dev/null}%
  \DeclareGraphicsAlien{.gif}{.eps}{convert '\SourceFile[0]' '\OutputFile'}%
\else% PDF and PNG are native formats with pdftex, xetex, and luatex.
  \DeclareGraphicsAlien{.svg}{.pdf}{%
    inkscape --export-type=pdf --export-area-page '\SourceFile' -o 
    '\OutputFile' 2>/dev/null}%
  \DeclareGraphicsAlien{.gif}{.png}{convert '\SourceFile[0]' \OutputFile}%
\fi
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Vector graphic \includegraphics{vector.svg}
\item Rasterized graphic \includegraphics{raster.gif}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Calls to `latex` must be detected because with this engine, PDF and PNG are not native graphics formats, contrarily to `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

Only the first frame of the animated GIF is converted (note the syntax `[0]` to ask this to ImageMagick's `convert`) and passed to the resulting document.

**Additional note** I should probably define what I call a *native graphics format*. I am not comfortable with this. Let say that in your TeX's engine driver for graphics (`dvips.def`, `pdftex.def`, `xetex.def`, or `luatex.def`), you find lines like `\@namedef{Gin@rule@.<XYZ>}#1{{<FMT>}{.<EXT>}{#1}}`. I would say that native formats are shown with their (non-empty) extension `.<EXT>`. For instance, I could not make BMP work as a native format with `latex/dvips`.